# ERC1155 without metadata uri

Tags: erc-1155

Is it possible to create ERC1155 without metadata uri?
At the moment I don't need metadata

Thanks

Comment: What is the NFT of?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mint NFT without giving value to the `bytes memory data` variable, you can just mint NFT by passing zero value `0x00` to it.